# Button not being added on navigation controller

Tags: ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ac = [[AddContacts alloc]init];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ac];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

    UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];          
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
}
```

Why is my button not being added on the navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIBarButtonItem`s are not controlled by the navigation controller, but by each of the view controllers it contains - each `UIViewController` can have different buttons. Try:

```
ac = [[AddContacts alloc]init];
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshPropertyList:)];          
ac.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

Then initialize the `UINavigationController` as you have been doing.

Comment: i did as you told me but new problem is when i am clicking button i am getting SIGABRT issue

Comment: Does the method `refreshPropertyList:` exist in this file or the `AddContacts` class?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here that could be causing issues.

Probably what the main issue is this line:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

I am pretty sure that what you want to be setting is the right bar button item on the `ac` view controller's navigation item.

```
ac.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton
```

A few other things though:

- Don't have two letter variable names. "ac" is very ambiguous, "addContacts" would provide more information, "addContactsViewController" would provide even more
- Are you implementing your own `navigationController` property in a `UIViewController` subclass?  This is not recommended as it is overriding the `navigationController` property that `UIViewController` already has.  Give it a different name.
- Is the `-viewDidLoad` method on the parent view controller the place to be assigning the right bar button of your AddContacts object?  Consider instead putting the code to set the bar button in the implementation of AddContacts instead.